# Thinking sphinx word match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

The data what i have is

kiran@test.com - first record
kiran1@test.com - second record

I need to search using the email address. I have forums and users indexed in my web app.

First scenario

I kept the '@' symbol in the charset table which is working fine problem is for example if the search keyword as 'kiran@test.com' it is giving me the exact result but if i user only 'test' no results found.

Second scenario

If i won't keep '@' symbol in the charset table. If the i use 'kiran@test.com' i am getting both the results and for 'test' also i am getting both the results

Expected Scenario

If i use the entire email 'kiran@test.com'  - I need to get only first record
If i use only 'test' - I need to get both the records

In plain mysql something like "select users where email like '%search-key%'"

I use the following code for searching

ThinkingSphinx.search params[:search_key],:star => Regexp.new('\w+@*\w+', nil, 'u') (I don't want to treat '@' as the separator)

Please suggest me any options i can pass to achieve the expected result.

Thanks
Kiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at blended char support

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-blend-chars

Or if you really what [ email like '%search-key%'" ] style support maybe min_infix_len. (leaving . and @ in charset table)

Answer (score 0):

To search for full email you could use Phrase Search operator.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax

So, if you could determine search query as email use "phrase search" otherwise use general search.